# I would like to remove all blank spaces in an array using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Here is a snippet of my program.

```
function onFormSubmit() {
var fr = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses')
var lastRowValues = fr.getRange(fr.getLastRow(), 2, 1, fr.getLastColumn()).getValues() 
Logger.log(lastRowValues)
var i = lastRowValues.length;    
while(i--) !/\S/.test(lastRowValues[i]) && lastRowValues.splice(i, 1);
Logger.log(lastRowValues)
}
```

[Here is the output, but as you can see my code does not remove the blank elements of the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0sQw.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 2D array. You're just testing the outer array(length:1), whereas you need to test the inner one.

```
var i = lastRowValues[0].length;    
while(i--) (!/\S/.test(lastRowValues[0][i])) && lastRowValues[0].splice(i, 1);
```

Comment: Nope. Needed coffee.